# "Would you mind and do something" in nonstandard colloquial AmEng

Tags: american-english, formality, colloquialisms, north-american-english, non-standard

Does ***Would you mind and do something*** instead of ***Would you mind doing something*** sound acceptable in spoken AmEng, or is it an attempt to imitate or render colloquial speech in not so formal writing?

> Would you mind and provide the phone number connected on the account? [source](http://forums.comcast.com/t5/Customer-Service/Talk-about-a-bottleneck-Very-unhappy/td-p/1576817)
>
> Would you mind and tell us what you've tried. [source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546883/does-this-function-satisfy-intermediate-value-property)
>
> Would you mind and not steal my Sig. [source](http://www.xtremesystems.org/forums/showthread.php?18931-XS-Case-Gallery/page65)
>
> Would you mind and not repeat that to anyone.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that Americans actually say this? Googling yields only found a very few examples of this construction. Americans do say "Can you try and ...", and "Would you go and …",  but this type of construction doesn't extend to most verbs, including "Would you mind and …"

Comment: As a nonnative speaker, "Would you mind and do" sounds to me like a corruption of "Would you mind doing" and "Would you do" and gives a note of informality to these grammatical constructions that might sound somewhat stilted in colloquial contexts such as a discussion among teenagers. Anyone to agree on that?

Comment: To me, it doesn't sound terrible, but it doesn't sound like anything an American English speaker is likely to say, either.

Comment: Here's another sourced example of "Would mind and do" you might want to consider: "Dear Sir, Would gou mind and tell me why you have bought this item from our store and not from someone else" http://totalprofitstrategy.com/optimal-choice-customer#more-497

Comment: It's not a made up sentence. It's a dialogue between two people, they sound native speakers to me. I think this is similar to a typo, a mistake that someone makes when they writing in a hurry.

Comment: What point is there in saying that a nonstandard or substandard colloquial expression is a typo when such construction clearly appears to be popular in colloquial contexts such as among young people communicating with each other?

Comment: The point is that the same person if writing a formal letter would probably not make that kind of error. That text is not literature, nor an academic paper. It's someone who was sending a flurry of messages to another. Mistakes do happen. Does this excerpt reflect modern day speech, could well be.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I quite agree with you on that point, but why call "Would mind and do" a mistake? Why not just say it's nonstandard, substandard, or something like that, and allow that it might reflect modern day colloquial speech and writing?

Comment: @PeterShor this construction also extends to such expressions as "Be sure" and "Take care". e.g. "Be sure and eat up all of your vegetables", "Take care and give me a call when you are in Italy", "Mind and do what you are told".

Comment: @Nourished: The second source you give is part of the statement *“Dear sir, would you mind and tell me why you have bought this item from our store and not from someone else? What would be the value you have got here that have prevailed over other similar store like ours?”*. The phrase *"over other similar store like ours"* does not appear to have been written by a native English speaker.

Comment: @PeterShor I concede it was a cheesy example. Would you then mind considering this other example: "Would you mind and get your old man a rabbit or an animal of some sort?" https://www.fanfiction.net/s/8655298/4/Burning

Comment: "For God's sake, would you mind and shut up and pay attention for once." http://www.wattpad.com/4083602-eye-of-the-storm

Comment: @Nourished: isn't that another meaning of *mind*? [mind](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mind): *to attend to closely.* I don't think there's any real reason that Americans don't say *"would you mind and …"*; it's not any less grammatical than *"would you try and …"*. But judging from how hard a time you are having finding examples, we don't say it very often.

Comment: The sense conveyed indeed is different -- it can be said in exasperation with a jocular or sarcastic tone -- but the meaning of mind still is the same, i.e. "Would you be so kind as to shut up and pay attention."

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Would you be kind enough and do something" in colloquial AE](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150761/would-you-be-kind-enough-and-do-something-in-colloquial-ae)

Comment: Would you mind takes the place of "please". Use it as you would use please.  You wouldn't say Please and hand me that.

Comment: @DavidM You wouldn't say "Please handing me that" either, would you? ;)

Comment: "Would you mind and do ..." is not standard, and causes one to wonder which sense of "mind" is being used.  It's not technically bad syntax, but it's meaning is, at best, ambiguous.

Comment: As a native American English speaker, I have never heard anyone use the phrase "would you mind and do...".  There are many other similar phrases which use "and", but not "would you mind".  One could say "would you be a doll and do..." or "would you be so kind as to do...".  The examples cited appear to be either typos or incorrect grammar.  A published source would be helpful in determining if this phrase has ever, in fact, come into popular use, but I don't believe it has.

Comment: Sounds just fine to me. Might even put a _“sweetheart”_ at the end, If'n an oldn is talking to a kidlet. (I LOVE questions like this that confuse and actually disturb the types of people who thrive here, with no real world experience, and who can only comprehend right and wrong (black and white) through _Google Books_, as if that is some kind of _definitive_ source for real life. When exacting translations of old movies comes online, with characters like Gabby Hayes, they'll have another database to think with, but that still won't come close to the richness of life, and our spoken history.)

Comment: @Larry Two thumbs up to that... when the question asks "Colloquial?" and get's hollers of "typo" it makes me think of hands that have never had a blister and collars whose whiteness have never been tarnished. The answer to this question would be best answered by sitting with a few cups of coffee in a small town diner at breakfast time. I doubt you'd find a single person who thinks anything off about being asked "Would you mind and pass me the paper?"

Comment: I don't think the question is so much "could it be understood" as "does it sound like something you've heard people say before". I can't say I've heard this particular formation. It honestly grates my nerves a little, like hearing someone from the Northeast US saying "y'all". It never sounds *comfortable*, even though they're using it correctly. ;)

Comment: I wonder if sometimes these phrases called "colloquial" could simply be one, single person's mash-up that the OP has heard over and over and wonders if it is a "thing".  Turns out that apparently I'm the only person who uses "punches up" as a synonym for a reminder: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/231775/am-i-the-only-person-to-use-punch-up-to-mean-remind-someone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.) "Would you mind and do something?"
>
> 2.) "Would you mind and provide the phone number connected on the account?"
>
> 3.) "Would you mind and tell us what you've tried."

According to my ear, there's nothing wrong with those types of expressions. (I'm an AmE speaker, and I've traveled to or lived in most corners of the USA.)

Actually, in my personal opinion, I'd consider those versions to be more polite than these alternatives:

- "Would you mind *doing* something?"
- "Would you mind *providing* the phone number connected on the account?"
- "Would you mind *telling* us what you've tried."

as those last three versions have the speaker sorta already assuming that the other person won't mind hearing a request from him, and the speaker is rushing a request at the other person. (Though others might disagree.)

As for the OP's #1, #2 and #3 examples, I've heard these kinds of phrases spoken often by AmE speakers, and I'm pretty sure I've used them myself. E.g. *"Would you mind and do something for me?"*

I'd consider these kinds of expressions to be at least of an informal style of standard English. The coordinator "and" has many uses, e.g. *"Be sure and lock up", "We always try and do our best"*. (There might be some related info in the 2002 reference grammar *CGEL*.)

Comment: I find this difficult to believe. I'm an AE speaker and I've *never* heard or used that construction!  Would you mind is a replacement for please. You wouldn't say "please and do this."

Comment: @DavidM I'm an AmE speaker, and I've heard and used it.

Comment: I don't think you could call it standard usage by any stretch, though.  There are 3 AmE speakers on this question who've never heard it.

Comment: @DavidM Well, are you sure you can claim that you've **never** heard it, really? -- Okay, so you got 3 speakers. And now what?

Comment: @DavidM Here's a serious question for you: Would you consider these two examples, *"Be sure and lock up"* and *"We always try and do our best"* to be non-standard?

Comment: Those are two different constructs.  The first one is non-standard, but common usage.  The second is perfectly standard.  The second is the same as saying We always try and we always do our best.

Comment: It depends upon your definition of standard English, I guess.

Comment: @DavidM So let me make sure I understand you. You are saying that *"Be sure and lock up"* is non-standard?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13263/discussion-between-david-m-and-f-e)

Comment: @DavidM Er, I can't -- for my login to chat always fails. And that is a good thing, since I'll probably waste too much time if chat did work. :) . . .

Comment: OK.  Well, here goes.  *Be sure and lock up.*  Yes it's used.  But, what does it mean?  It means, be certain, and lock up, too.  *Be sure to lock up.*  Means can you make certain you lock up.

Comment: @DavidM But are you (still) saying that *"Be sure and lock up"* is non-standard?

Comment: Yes.  On the basis that it is just not a correct construct.

Comment: @DavidM What about the "try and V" constructions, do you think they are non-standard? For example *"We always try and do our best"*, is that non-standard?

Comment: As I've said, it is standard.  It means "We try and We do our best."  That is a perfectly natural construct.

Comment: Getting back to the original.  Would you mind and do the following?  That's asking would you mind and would you do the following.  Why would you ask someone to mind?

Comment: @DavidM One more, :) -- How about *"He's been and gone and told the teacher"*, is that non-standard?

Comment: That one is logical.  But, it sounds . . . goofy.  I would write that as *He's been, gone, and told the teacher.*

Comment: May I ask if you're a Southerner?

Comment: @DavidM Historically, in some of these constructions, the word "and" has the meaning of today's "to". And so, that's sorta why some of these constructions have been sorta grandfathered into today's English.

Comment: @DavidM Er, I'm a yankee. Well, not a New Englander yankee, but near there.

Comment: @DavidM Well, you might want to know that the examples I've been typing in, er, I've been copying out of the 2002 reference grammar *CGEL* by Huddleston and Pullum et al. All the examples are considered by them to be standard English, though most of them are of informal style -- though, that one *"He's been and gone and told the teacher"* they consider to be very colloquial.

Comment: I will admit that I've been bested.  They all sound goofy and colloquial.  But, I guess that's standard English by some definitions.  They sound particularly Southern or country to my ear.  Do me a favor.  Edit your post even to delete a character, so I can reverse my down vote.

Comment: @DavidM I suppose I could add this info and more supportive info into my post, but then my post would balloon up into a couple of pages and would involve a good amount of time. And I'm trying to watch *Perry Mason* on TV right now . . .

Comment: Yes.  It would be much more useful that way.  And, it would prevent firebrand purists who hate colloquial usage like myself from handing out down votes.

Comment: @DavidM But if I don't edit my post, then ah got ya stuck with a guilty feeling for all your long days! :)

Comment: I'll get over it fairly quickly.  It's the fault of Huddleston and Pullum for having such low standards!

Comment: @DavidM Actually, the blame is on the older Englishes. A lot of current constructions (that might seem informal in style) are from those days, and since they were and are so much in use, then they stayed around. Actually, I'm just in the middle of reviewing some material which happen to also be related to our discussion, which is the topic "Asymmetric constructions -- 'and'". What a coincidence!

Comment: This is non-standard American English, contrary to F.E.'s claim.  To my ear, and probably the majority of speakers of SAE, this sounds ungrammatical and incorrect.

Comment: @MunchyWilly Okayee then. Prove your claim. Post your answer, and use vetted grammatical sources to back it up. (Oh, thanks for the down vote.)

Comment: @F.E. I am satisfied with other answers already provided.  The OED provides no intransitive use of *mind* similar to what you're positing that is not labeled regional or colloquial.  Just because 'and' can replace 'to' in some constructions, doesn't mean that it's acceptable in all - "...mind and..." being one of them.  People do say this, but it's not standard, and still sounds as such to most speakers.  I downvoted because I think your answer is faulty in claiming the acceptableness and the increased politeness of such constructions.  It's nothing personal.

Comment: @MunchyWilly You said "**People do say this,** but it's not standard, and still sounds as such to most speakers"; and so, since you admit that people do say it, the onus is now on you to prove that usage is non-standard. A reasonable grammatical explanation might be helpful to your cause. You've declared *"This is non-standard American English"*, so let's see you back up your claim. Otherwise, your claim has the strength of tissue paper. It's nothing personal.

Comment: It is non-standard enough that I notice it when I hear it, and I very rarely hear it among literate people.  It would be fairly "standard" among those who, eg, interchange "bring" and "take", a widespread subset of American English speakers concentrated primarily in rural areas.  (And you have provided nothing to back up your claims that it is "standard".)

Comment: (Understand that "mind", in this context, means "object to".  The only other sense of "mind" that might possibly apply would be "take care of", but that doesn't really fit the context of a simple request.)

Comment: @HotLicks, ig'nant speaking isn't isolated to rural areas, of course, and "bring/take" abuse can be colloquial usage as it was where I grew up (suburban Chicago).  I still am occasionally guilty of "bringing the potato salad" which gives my non-native-born husband fodder to correct me - to his delight. :-)

Answer (score 11):

AmE here.

"Would you mind and do something" is unacceptable in any region of the US in which I have ever lived (Northeast, Mid-Atlantic, South, Mid-west and Northwest.) It is not idiomatic, and at best is a terrible example of attempt at simulating non-native speech.

Googling "would you mind and do" turns up no examples of this phrasing except your own question. The most common hit is for two polite phrases

> "Would you mind" and "do you mind"...

We *do* have bizarre idiomatic speech pockets (as with PA Dutch), but none quite that bizarre.

Comment: I agree. Would you mind is equivalent to please.  You'd never say "Please and do this."!

Answer (score 6):

I was interested in seeing what use authors have historically made of the construction "mind and [other verb]," along the lines of the poster's wording "would you mind and do something." So I ran Google Books searches for three phrases—"now mind and," "mind and do," and "you mind and"—for the period 1600–2008. These searches yielded quite a few matches, going back to at least 1721 and continuing (probably) until at least 1947.

However, none of the matches attempt to connect *mind* in the sense of "disapprove" or "object" or "be unwilling" (which appears to be the sense of *mind* that the OP intends) with another verb via a conjunctive *and*. Instead most of the relevant instances use *mind* in the sense of "pay attention" or "remember" or "obey."

---

***Examples from England, 1721–1908***

Examples of this usage go back to England in the early 1700s. From James Naylor, [*A Collection of Sundry Books, Epistles and Papers Written by James Nayler*](https://books.google.com/books?id=AWJPAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA521&dq=%22now+mind+and%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3usbCnc7KAhWGloMKHSfoBnMQ6AEILjAD#v=onepage&q=%22now%20mind%20and%22&f=false) (London, 1721):

> High carnal minds seek high things, and so they grow lofty and proud, and such God resists, and keeps them afar off: but the poor in spirit seek truth and meekness, and are fed thereof at the table of the Lord; meek, and lowly and just, and faithful are all his household, who feed and sup with him. Now **mind and consider** your ways, who are gone out unto the mountains to worship and feed yourselves, you may read of Israel's sin in going out from the temple, in which the Lord had said he would dwell, and be enquired of, and they built altars without him, and there called upon him but found him not, for which he rejected their worships, and their temple also.

From Edmund Calamy, [*A Continuation of the Account of the Ministers, Lecturers, Masters and Fellows of Colleges, and Schoolmasters, who were Ejected and Silenced after the Restoration in 1660*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ENEiP8AwAJ4C&pg=PA308&dq=%22mind+and+do%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjk5_G2uM7KAhUFNSYKHYH1BcUQ6AEIQDAG#v=onepage&q=%22mind%20and%20do%22&f=false) (1727), citing a letter of unidentified date:

> Keep close to GOD daily. **Mind and do** his Work thoroughly, and you will find 'tis most delightful. Find out and close with some pious, studious, ingenious Youths, and make them your familiar Acquaintance. Take heed you neglect not publick holy Duties. Remember the Sabbath to sanctify it.

From Isaac Penington, [*The Works of the Long-Mournful and Sorely-Distressed Isaac Penington*](https://books.google.com/books?id=dfhLAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA117&dq=%22now+mind+and%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8lO2yls7KAhVN02MKHQphCu4Q6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22now%20mind%20and%22&f=false), volume 2, second edition (London, 1761):

> Now **mind and remember** this which followeth:

From a [letter of August 12, 1808](https://books.google.com/books?id=5CswAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA42&dq=%22now+mind+and%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8lO2yls7KAhVN02MKHQphCu4Q6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=%22now%20mind%20and%22&f=false), in *Extraordinary Life and Character of Mary Bateman, the Yorkshire Witch*, twelfth edition (Leeds, 1811).

> MY DEAR FRIEND.—I send you these few lines to let you know that I shall get to Wittwell in Boland on Friday next, so I could wish make yourself happy thou love of mine, till thou see me tap thy shoulder for it would not do for the to know the moment, for it would put the in such fear and do not let Mary reed this letter of freedoms, for I have not wrote to hr for a long time, and for her husband i not likely to get no better and he says it is long of you and wont hardly let her stur, you may tell her to make her self easy on me not sending to her, it is for a reason, now **mind and bury** this near the other.

From [*The Novitiate's Preceptor; Or, Religious and Literary Register for the New Church*](https://books.google.com/books?id=H0xgAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA170&dq=%22mind+and+do%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5pIqNu87KAhXBnYMKHag3Aj4Q6AEIJzAC#v=onepage&q=%22mind%20and%20do%22&f=false), volume 1 (London, 1827):

> May I put him [a dead squirrel buried in a china vase] into a halfpint stone-mug that is in the house, and then fasten the top of this box over it? Aye, aye, replied Mr. Rotchford, you may do that if you please; so away ran Kitty for the stone mug, and Charles for the spade, with which he directly began to dig for the squirrel. Take care, Charles, said his father, **mind and do** that carefully, or you will break the tureen and all your labour will be useless.

From a [letter from James Rush to his son James](https://books.google.com/books?id=FlUEAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA20&dq=%22mind+and+do+not+let+them+take%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwia2obQx87KAhWFkYMKHchPCmUQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22mind%20and%20do%20not%20let%20them%20take%22&f=false) (April 20, 1848), in *An Introductory Narrative and a Revised Report of the Trial and Execution of J. B. Rush* (1849):

> Direct for me at the Shoreditch station, and **mind and write** me a long letter of every thing that has taken place. If they have token possession, **mind and do** not let them take anything away, or meddle with any of my papers; but as I said before, if they are not yet on, keep them out of the house at all events till you see me on Sunday morning, and do not let any one know when I am coming.

From Andrew Lang, "[Brother and Sister](https://books.google.com/books?id=l2DIBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT95&dq=%22now+mind+and%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-_PTvyM7KAhWBk4MKHYglAvAQ6AEIKDAC#v=onepage&q=%22now%20mind%20and%22&f=false)," in *The Red Fairy Book* (1893):

> 'Sister, open the door, I must get out.'
>
> So sister opened the door and said, 'Now **mind and get back** by nightfall, and say your little rhyme.'

And from Kenneth Grahame, [*The Wind in the Willows*](https://books.google.com/books?id=bqhaAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA184&dq=%22now+mind+and%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiczuifx87KAhWKvYMKHU_BCCkQ6AEILTAD#v=onepage&q=%22now%20mind%20and%22&f=false) (1908):

> When we are through [the tunnel], I will shut off steam and put on brakes as hard as I can, and the moment it's safe to do so you must jump and hide in the wood, before they get through the tunnel and see you. Then I will go full speed ahead again, and they can chase me if they like, for as long as they like, and as far as they like. Now **mind and be** ready to jump when I tell you!

---

***Examples from North America, 1725–1887***

Similar examples appear in letters by colonial Americans by 1725 and in books by American authors by 1825. From a modern history citing a [letter by JC [James Crokatt?], August 24, 1725](https://books.google.com/books?id=4voBZqHuCIUC&pg=PA117&dq=%22now+mind+and%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiH3dDss87KAhXltYMKHVd_Cq8Q6AEIJzAC#v=onepage&q=%22now%20mind%20and%22&f=false), in *The Southern Frontier, 1670–1732* (2004):

> It was an Indian, the head warrior of Tennessee, who, according to Colonel Chicken, agent at the same period among the Cherokee, 'got up and made the following Speech to me and the People of the Town. "That they must now **mind and Consider** that all their Old men were gone, and that they have been brought up after another Manner than their forefathers and that they must Consider that they could not live without the English."

From A Lady, [*Stranger of the Valley: Or, Louisa and Adelaide*](https://books.google.com/books?id=-QJFAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA207&dq=%22now+mind+and%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmo9ndoM7KAhWo74MKHaITDFQ4ChDoAQghMAE#v=onepage&q=%22now%20mind%20and%22&f=false) (New York, 1825):

> Laluce strongly opposed this measure [a plan of action suggested by uncle Charles], for he greatly feared they would refuse to bestow their incomparable daughter on a person who had so long  depended on their bounty, and whose connections they were unacquainted with; but uncle Charles insisted on having his way, or he would do nothing about it, and Laluce was obliged to submit.
>
> "Now **mind and work** your card right," said the delighted uncle Charles, "and if you fairly set out for it, my dear boy, you can make up a story equal to any one."

From Susanna Moodie, [*Richard Redpath*](https://books.google.com/books?id=4JwLAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA443&dq=%22now+mind+and%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZ7ojdps7KAhWrwYMKHQBaClQ4ChDoAQg8MAY#v=onepage&q=%22now%20mind%20and%22&f=false), in *The Literary Garland, and British North American Magazine* (Montreal, October 1843):

> "Well, well, Bess! You may have him," returned the planter. "But you spoil all your slaves. Now **mind and keep** a strict eye over him. If he is such a good cook, he will spare you a world of trouble."

From Theodore Fay, [*Hoboken: A Romance of New York*](https://books.google.com/books?id=J7IcAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA199&dq=%22you+mind+and%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjomrftws7KAhWlyIMKHRoPCvwQ6AEISTAJ#v=onepage&q=%22you%20mind%20and%22&f=false), volume 1 (1843):

> "Pooh, pooh, Katy! what a superfine Spartan mother you would have made! I fancy your presenting Frank his shield and telling him 'with it or upon it!'"
>
> Mother would say," interrupted Mary, laughing, "'with it or without it! but, at all events, do you **mind and come** home!'"

From Joanna Mathews, [*Belle Powers' Locket*](https://books.google.com/books?id=_AcCAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA128&dq=%22Now+mind+and+keep+the+door+shut%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1vfTkrs7KAhVBroMKHW5MANMQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22Now%20mind%20and%20keep%20the%20door%20shut%22&f=false) in *Little Sunbeams* (London, 1872 [but Mathews was born in New York, and wrote and lived in the United States]):

> A door in the side of the garden wall opened upon the street which bounded one side of it; and, unfastening this, the cook passed out,saying to Marcia,—
>
> "Now **mind and keep** the door shut; and don't you be poking your head out, and leaving your work."

From Mrs. S.E. Dawes, "[Out in the Cold: A Story for Girls](https://books.google.com/books?id=KTRAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA258-IA2&dq=%22Now+that+some+one+has+at+last+given+you+a+home%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjs2ZK5xc7KAhVDmoMKHZLIDDIQ6AEIHzAA#v=onepage&q=%22Now%20that%20some%20one%20has%20at%20last%20given%20you%20a%20home%22&f=false)," *Our Boys and Girls* (New York, April 1873):

> "We are well met," said he, "for I have something to say to you, Kate Somers. Now that some one has at last given you a home, do you **mind and keep** it. If you don't like, you needn't think of going back to the city, for no one will take you at the Home you left."

From "[Buds, Blossoms & Leaves](https://books.google.com/books?id=ktJNAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA10&dq=%22now+mind+and%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjT_f_8r87KAhVkkYMKHSsHAEIQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22now%20mind%20and%22&f=false)," in *Popular Gardening and Fruit Growing* (Buffalo, Ne York, October 1886):

> Now **mind and plant** your bulbs, mainly in clumps, each sort by itself.

From [*Grammar School*](https://books.google.com/books?id=TxALYFDcdQYC&q=%22She+seemed+very+near+me,+somehow,+as+I+sewed%22&dq=%22She+seemed+very+near+me,+somehow,+as+I+sewed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjiysXQss7KAhVHuIMKHfDWDqoQ6AEIHTAA), issue 6 (Chicago & Boston, 1887) [combined snippets]:

> I had it [a night-cap] off in a second, and I saw my mother's basting threads in the hem. She seemed very near me, somehow, as I sewed and sewed, until it was really finished at last. But every stitch I put in had the same word to say for itself. One said, "Now **mind, and finish** the next thing!" And another one said, "Now **mind and finish** the next thing!" And another one said, "Now **mind and finish** the next thing!" until I got pretty tired of it.

---

***Conclusions***

The reason "Would you mind and do something" sounds vaguely plausible as colloquial American (or British) English is that the wording "mind and [do something]" *was* in at least occasional usage in parts of the English-speaking world for at least a couple of centuries. But two points are essential in accurately appraising the significance of this fact.

First, the recorded usage of the phrase involves *mind* being used in the sense of "pay mind to"—that is, "pay attention" or "remember" or "obey." That is not at all the meaning of *mind* in the OP's example; there, the meaning is "disapprove" or "object" or "be unwilling." But in the dozens of relevant matches that Google Books found in the searches I conducted, the construction "mind [as a verb] and [some other verb]" never used *mind* in that sense.

Second, the Google Books results strongly suggest that the "mind and [another verb]" formulation has rarely been used in published writing in the past century, and that the wording is moribund. The last example from the United States that seems to use the phrase in the old way is Marguerite McIntire, [*Carey Brown*](https://books.google.com/books?id=EEVCAAAAIAAJ&q=%22now+mind+and%22&dq=%22now+mind+and%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMjJSXzs7KAhVD_mMKHeBwBBIQ6AEIIjAB) (New York, 1942):

> "I'll give you a small pail to pick into," Mrs. Steven said, "and a larger one for dumping in. You've got to pick clean. I won't pay you anything for dirty berries; no sticks, no leaves, no green ones. Now **mind. And pick** with the tips of your fingers so's you won't rub the bloom off. Think you can do it all right?"

And the last British example may be from [*The National Review: The English Review*](https://books.google.com/books?id=1rDQAAAAMAAJ&q=%22now+mind+and%22&dq=%22now+mind+and%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdpZTC1s7KAhVRymMKHYaEANc4ChDoAQggMAE) (1947):

> "Here you are, Sir, they were no' quite dry before. Now **mind, and fold** the meat this way, John, or you'll lose the blood. This label's no' on firm enough — I'll re-tie it." She looked fine, Mrs. Goodwins, in her spotless white overalls, with her laughing eyes.

So strike one is that historically "mind and [another verb]" never used *mind* in the way that the OP wants to use it. Strike two is that usage of the wording in the way that was fairly popular once upon a time has dropped off considerably since the late 1800s. And strike three is that the OP not only wants *mind* to mean "disapprove" or "object", but also wants to frame the wording as a conditional question. Here again, the Google Books search results do not yield a single match that illustrates similar manipulation of the phrasing to pose a conditional question.

Taking all of these considerations into account, I think that the OP's wording may stir readers' memories of superficially similar wording in *The Wind in the Willows*, *The Red Fairy Book*, and elsewhere—and thus may strike those readers as being potentially valid as colloquial language from somewhere else. But there is no record of a genuinely similar usage in Google Books, and I think the OP's wording has probably never been used un-self-consciously by a colloquial English speaker in North America or the UK.

Answer (score 4):

I think that's either a transcription error or extremely non-standard.

> = Would you mind providing the phone number connected with the account

mind and provide don't functional as separate verbs here. The main verb is **mind** and providing the phone number is the clause that is being asked about.

Comment: “Providing” is the verb. We are not talking about “minding the store,” we are inquiring about the person’s “state of mind.” We are saying “would it bother you to provide the phone number connected with the account?”

Answer (score 1):

AmEng here. *Would you mind and do something* sounds entirely bizarre to me.

To me, the definition of "mind" in these cases is "to be annoyed or upset about something." -- Substituting that definition, the "and" separates the verb that would be annoying. It makes no sense:

> Would you be annoyed *and* provide the phone number?

vs.

> Would you be annoyed providing the phone number?

On the other hand, perhaps this has some relation to the colloquial expression "try and do" vs. "try doing" : [see a related answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/289152/20482).

Answer (score 1):

The expression is “would you mind to … ?”

“Would you mind?” means “would it bother you?”

> Would you mind [to] provide the phone number connected [with] the account?
>
> Would you mind [to] tell us what you've tried?
>
> Would you mind [not to] steal my Sig?
>
> Would you mind [not to] repeat that to anyone?

So it is “Would it bother you not to repeat that to anyone?”

In American English, it is more common to hear it like this, though:

> [Do] you mind [providing] the phone number connected [with] the account?
>
> [Do] you mind [telling] us what you've tried?
>
> [Do] you mind [not stealing] my Sig?
>
> [Do] you mind [not repeating] that to anyone?

Answer (score 0):

This is very like "Try and see if you can do it"; I've been told that this phrase is not strictly wrong but is considered a "juvenile construction."