# "Show someone through" for "show someone around" in AE

Tags: american-english

Just wondering, can "show through" be used interchangeably with "show around" in AE?

"Trained docents will be delighted to show you through the house."
http://www.hewhs.com/museum/

Comment: Just wondering, when are you going to stop posting a multitude of similar questions. It's also suspicious that nearly all your quoted sources come from pdf files. Coincidence?

Comment: In that source, they're ***not*** interchangeable. "Show you through" means something more like "show you in". [Here's an example](http://www.metrolyrics.com/cemetery-lyrics-say-anything.html).

Comment: @PeterShor Why's that? Why aren't they interchangeable? Would you mind and spell it out to me in plain English? ;)

Comment: "Show you in": would be used when showing somebody the way to get to an office where he as an appointment. "Show you around": would be to give somebody a tour of some place. Your source has "show you through" under "receiving visitors", so there it's a synonym of "show you in". The song lyrics I linked to have them "showing you through" a gate, which is again like escorting you in.

Comment: @Mari-LouA What are you talking about? My questions look and sound to me nowhere near similar. ;)

Comment: @PeterShor Ok. So, in what context can "show someone through" be interchangeable with "show someone around"? In addition, would you say that "show someone through" is more commonly used in AE than in BE?

Comment: I would think "show somebody through" can be synonymous with "show somebody in", but ***not*** with "show somebody around". It's much rarer than "show somebody in", an expression which I think is quite common in both AE and BE.

Comment: @PeterShor Ok. Then, would you mind and consider that other example that I might just as well post in the OP ;) "Trained docents will be delighted to show you through the house." http://www.hewhs.com/museum/

Comment: OK … there it means "show you around".

Comment: Nevertheless, show you around the house, has to be (aha!) more common. Google Ngram, anyone?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=show+you+through+the+house%2C+show+you+around+the+house&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshow%20you%20through%20the%20house%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshow%20you%20around%20the%20house%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's got to be more common in prose, but how about in speech? Have you personally ever heard of such usage of "show someone through" in the sense of "show someone around"?

Comment: Can't say that I have, and besides I live in Italy and people tend to speak Italian. I would still opt for "show you around" if you want to be clearly understood.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Have you ever lived in the U.S.?

Comment: Never, unfortunately. But I have American friends who I write to.

Comment: Okey doke. Sounds good!

Comment: @Nourished Gourmet: Do you actually take any notice of what you're told about "normal" English usage here on ELU? I notice that in your above comments to Peter you've used "mind and xxx" in highly non-standard ways *twice*. But several hours earlier Peter had (somewhat patiently, imho) explained to you that such usages [*don't sound like anything an American English speaker is likely to say*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150758/would-you-mind-and-do-something-in-substandard-colloquial-ae#comment311853_150758)

Answer (score 3):

"Show you through [somewhere]" is definitely used for "show you around" in BrE (or at least in some BrE variants). Note that "Let me show you through", without other context, would mean through a gate/door/foyer etc, but "Let me show you through the house/office/building" means "show you around/give you a tour of".

This search for "'[show you through' the house](https://www.google.com/search?q=show%20you%20through&rlz=1C1CHWA_enCA533CA533&oq=show%20you%20through&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2047j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22show%20you%20through%22%20the%20house)" has hits from Canada, Australia, New Zealand, and US, and those for "'[show you through' the property](https://www.google.com/search?q=show%20you%20through&rlz=1C1CHWA_enCA533CA533&oq=show%20you%20through&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2047j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22show%20you%20through%22%20the%20property)" are largely from Australia and New Zealand.