# "Put over" for "put off" in AE

Tags: american-english, word-usage

In AE, can "put over" interchange with "put off" in the sense "postpone" in all contexts, or only in some specific ones?

I'm all the more anxious to know the answer as I didn't get any hits searching Google for "put over my (and your) appointment".

*By 6:00 P.M., the arbitrator **put over** the meeting...*
http://www.yonkerstribune.com/2013/01/arbitration-case-in-city-of-yonkers-vs-firefighters-local-628-postponed-to-february-1-2013-by-hezi-a.html

Comment: I've never heard "put over" used that way. (AE, Midwest US) BTW, not the down-voter.

Comment: That's not American usage. In the USA, "put over `st` on `so`" is an idiom meaning to fool someone: _They put one over on Bill last night_ means some people fooled Bill (probably as a joke, but maybe not). See also the different usages of American vs British usages of _table the motion_.

Comment: I thought of that too @JohnLawler, but actually that's "put *one* over"...  I'm not sure that's the same thing.

Comment: @JohnLawler Well, I just checked back online, and both Merriam-Wenster and The American Heritage Dictionary (aka The Free Online Dictionary" explicitly say it means "postpone/delay". To top it all off, it's defined as an AE equivalent for "put off, postpone" in each and every comprehensive bilingual dictionary out here in France. Maybe it's typical to some US states only.

Comment: Good, then you can believe them. After all, they're authorities, so how could they possibly be incorrect? Did they give you quotations from American sources? With usage counts?

Comment: @JohnLawler I just wanted to make sure it's typical enough in the U.S. that I can use it quite safely in conversations and general correspondence. ;)

Comment: Depends on who you're conversing and corresponding with. I wouldn't use it in written discourse without an identifying phrase like _until the 15th of next month_. It will be recognized, as UK legal/political usage, by those who've read classic British mysteries like Dorothy Sayers', but that seems unlikely to constitute a majority among American lawyers, at least. In speech, your conversational partner can query if it's not clear.

Comment: @Nourished Gourmet: These counts from Google Books may be useful... [put **off** until tomorrow](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22put+off+until+tomorrow%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):97,000 hits, [put **over** until tomorrow](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22put+over+until+tomorrow%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):2,070 hits. Also note [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=put+over+until&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cput%20over%20until%3B%2Cc0) showing the steep decline in ***over*** over the past half-century...

Comment: ...Why are you so interested in trying to drum up support for quirky, dialectal, and/or dated variants on ***standard*** English?

Comment: ...I disagree with the closevote claiming this is General Reference, since (as John says) if you believe everything you read in the dictionary you're likely to be somewhat out of touch with current usage. But I'd still like to know *why* you keep asking questions where you've apparently already established that there's "something wrong" (otherwise, why would you ask at all?).

Comment: ...finally, at 29 questions after only 6 days, you might like to take note of the fact that apparently Stack Exchange operates a policy: [Users are only permitted to ask 50 questions within a calendar-month, as a deterrent to help vampires.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monthly-question-limit)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Alleluia! Your last three comments are like cough medicine to my tickly throat!

Comment: @Mari-Lou: (embarrassed cough) You might like [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150848/show-someone-through-for-show-someone-around-in-ae#comment314274_150848) too then! I'm just hacked off with OP because I've just spent *ages* wading through an inordinately long review queue that seems to be mostly made up of *his* questions. And it's not that they're *all* bad, but after a while the eyes start to glaze over, and the mouse auto-locates the "close" button.

Comment: @FumbleFingers love the link on [Help vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) but wouldn't necessary classify the OP as being such, although the bit about "By nature they feed on generous individuals who tend towards helping others, and leave their victims exhausted, bitter and dispirited." is alone justified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

American Heritage also lists as "To postpone; delay".

It's something I've heard (AE, Midwest/California) but would never use myself. If you were going to use it, I think it would be best in the form "put over to [tomorrow/the next day/Friday]", to be clear on the meaning. "Put over" sounds more like something that would happen to a meeting or specific scheduled thing; but I tend to think you can "put off" any activity. "Put off" is much more common in my experience. In some contexts it can have a connotation of procrastination to it, though. "We keep putting that off."

It may be that "put over" is more frequently used on the East Coast, based on your Yonkers citation and that fact that we have two midwesterners here who are not very familiar with it. Google n-gram viewer shows "put off" as about [five times more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=put%20off,%20put%20over&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,put%20off;,c0;.t1;,put%20over;,c0) than "put over".

Comment: I've lived on the East Coast (D.C., New Jersey and Massachusetts) for much of my life, and I don't think I've ever heard it. If you search "put over until" in Google books, it definitely seems to be American, and you get lots for results from the 19th century, so it's a nearly archaic American expression.

Answer (score 0):

I'm from Philadelphia, and have lived in the Midwest and South.  I've never heard of "put over" for postponed.