# Usage of "try and…"

Tags: conjunctions, syntactic-analysis, gerunds, bare-infinitive

Which is the right sentence?

1. People have always tried and *be* up to date about what the latest news have been

or

2. People have always tried and *being* up to date…

Comment: Hi @Luis!  Neither sentence is correct -  "and" doesn't belong in either of those sentences.  You might want to check out our sister site: http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Neither. *Try and X* is a colloquial expression which is only available in certain tenses. It isn't used in any past or continuous forms:

Possible:

> I will try and fix it.
>
> I'm going to try and fix it.
>
> If I try and fix it, ...
>
> You could try and fix it.
>
> It should be possible to try and fix it.

Not possible:

> *I tried and fixed it.
>
> *I am trying and fixing it.
>
> *I was trying and fixing it.
>
> *I have tried and fixed it.

In all forms it can be replaced by *try to fix* (and some people feel that that is the only acceptable form, at least in formal use), and that form can be used in any tense.

**Edit**: the forms in the past are grammatical, but have a different meaning. *Try and fix it* refers to one activity or event (which is perhaps why some people prefer *try to fix it*). *I tried and fixed it* refers to two events - the trying and the fixing. They may not have been separate (eg I tried for several minutes and then succeeded) but there was a definite stage of trying before I fixed it. *I'll try and fix it* does not have that implication.

Comment: `I tried and fixed it.`  works fine i.e `I HAVE tried and I HAVE fixed it`. Although in the context you probably mean it would be `I tried to fix it`. I assume you already know this and this comment is purely for OP.

Comment: @123: You're right that that is grammatical; but it is not an instance of the idiom. See my edit to my answer.

Comment: Also, "try and" can only be used in the positive.  You can't say "I am trying not and cough".  In the negative, it has to be "try to"; or "try not to", to be precise.